# What service can email groups and keeps all members' emails private from each other?

Tags: web-apps, email, web-services, privacy

What service allows me to create a group mailing list, give people the ability to subscribe and unsubscribe to the list on their own but keep private everyone's email address from all other users, including the moderators and owners of said group?

An example use case would be to create a group mailing list for residents of condominiums. Each resident could email the group of subscribers all at once by sending an email to a group address and recipients would know who it was from (or at least their username) but not the sender's actual email used to send the message. Also, the creator/owner of the group would not be able to find out the email addresses of the residents who subscribed.

Comment: And I assume also *...including the sender email address*. That rules out e.g. Google groups where you have a 'list' amail adress but you also see (only) the sender email address (so that you can choose to reply to the entire list/group or the sender only).

Comment: *Residents could email each other* Please [edit]: Do you mean *all at once*, or also individually, e.g. by nickname? Please distinguish very clearly **name** and **email**.

Comment: I do not know any service of the kind (though it may exist). Just another idea that might help you: [message boards and forums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum) do exactly what you ask, only not in your mailbox, though most of them have notification settings to send mail to you when a new message is added on a thread. Plus: every user can keep their email address private. Maybe you can have a look there. [Some software ideas on Wikipedia: click!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software)

Answer (score 2):

Most well known Mail Newsletter Web Apps can hide all other members emails. You can too if you CC them. For newsletter apps, I would personnly use Sendy due to its extremly low cost solution powered by Amazon but being that you want a service, here are a few I would recommend. (And Yes, they will hide all members, moderators, and owners email BUT you will have to setup a send from email, usually like no-reply@domain.tdl)

**[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/)**
This is a highly known email service. It is an easy to send email newsletters to your customers, manage your subscriber lists, and track campaign performance. It also has it's own email builder.
[image: MailChimp's Interface]

**[Campayn](http://campayn.com/)**
Campayn allows you to create, share and track email newsletters and marketing emails. The 'Free for Life' plan allows you to send 20,000 emails to 2,000 contacts per month. Includes robust features like list segmentation, contact level reporting and ROI tracking. All your emails are responsive and look great on mobile devices.
[image: Campayn Interface]

**[Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/)**
Campaign Monitor offers everything a designer needs to run successful email marketing campaigns for themselves and their clients. You can even rebrand the interface, create sub-accounts for your clients and let them send their own campaigns.
[image: Campaign Monitor Interface]

Comment: These are great tools, but I think it misses one of the OP's requirements: "Each resident could email the group of subscribers all at once by sending an email to a group address." The search seems rather to be for a service providing group addresses.

Comment: My mistake, I will keep looking